# TabLayout v23 doesn't scroll with ViewPager scroll

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

With the new design support library 23.0.0, the tabs for `TabLayout` are not being scrolled at the time you drag the `ViewPager` asociated. The tabs are only scrolled when you finish the dragging and click up (when the tab is already selected). This was working fine on 22.2.1

Do I have to add something more to get it work like in 22.2.1? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

Bug fixed with the last version 23.0.1

Comment: Google issue described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround that solves it, proposed by [Chris Banes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474997/chris-banes) (The main developer of the design support library). This issue was mentioned on the Google Issues page [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184105), and solved [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183123).

Put this code when setting the `ViewPager`:

```
    viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners();
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Also add this class:

```
private static class TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final WeakReference<TabLayout> mTabLayoutRef;
    private int mPreviousScrollState;
    private int mScrollState;

    public TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        mTabLayoutRef = new WeakReference<>(tabLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mPreviousScrollState = mScrollState;
        mScrollState = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        final TabLayout tabLayout = mTabLayoutRef.get();
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            final boolean updateText = (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                    || (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
                    && mPreviousScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
            tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, positionOffset, updateText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        final TabLayout tabLayout = mTabLayoutRef.get();
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }
    }
}
```